# Vim: <leader>h mapping slow

Tags: vim

I am not very good with vimscript, but I am trying to do some custom mappings in Vim. What I want to do is map `<leader>h` to switch to the previous tab, but when I press `<leader>` followed by `h`, it's waiting for another key and doesn't switch quickly. Is there a way to see what mappings are there starting with the "h" key and unmapping them? Or maybe another, more elegant solution?

Thanks,
H.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To see all your mappings, type `:map`. To see what mapping(s) apply to a given prefix, like your `h` situation, type `:map <leader>h`.

What’s likely happening is that you have some other `h`-mappings that take multiple characters. E.g., if you also have `map <leader>hx`, then vim will pause for `timeoutlen` milliseconds (see `:help tm` and also `ttm`) before trying to honor your shorter `<leader>h`, in case you’re actually trying to type the longer one.

So you’ll need to track down where your longer mapping are coming from and possibly remove them.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably what's happening. So how do I see if there are <leader>hx mappings?

Comment: To see all h-mappings, just type: :map <leader>h

Answer (score 0):

Thats Because You need to add enter key also :)

```
let mapleader = "z"
nnoremap <leader>n :tabe<Enter>
```